# Dependency on slf4j causes ClassLoader conflict

Tags: java, maven, jira, classloader, slf4j

I'm working on jira addon. When I try to deploy it, I receive an error:

> Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in URL [bundle://205.0:1/com/softwareplant/tool/service/UserService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

In the project I use such dependencies:

```
[0;37m[INFO] +- com.atlassian.jira:jira-core:jar:7.0.0:provided[0m
[0;37m[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.9:provided[0m
[0;37m[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.9:provided[0m
[0;37m[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.9:provided[0m
[0;37m[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile[0m
```

Hope you have ideas how to deal with that. Thanks for any help! 
 thanks for any help!

Comment: If `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.9` is "provided", then `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.9` is likely also "provided", so don't include `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25` as a "compile" dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This happen sometimes if you have 2 different versions of the same library, try to clean the project and run again.

Comment: Indeed, one of my project's dependency was unwittingly overriding `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` causing a `java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;"`. A Maven exclusion did the trick.